# Accessing Object in View with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have an customer object whose fields I'm trying to access in my view with Thymeleaf. I've used the usual syntax i.e:

```
<p th:text="${customer.name}"></p>
```

however, this does not work, it does work when I use the get() method i.e:

```
<p th:text="${customer.get.name}"></p>
```

Any idea why that is happening? I'm just getting started with Thymeleaf, so I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question.

Here's my Model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, message="Company name length must be at least 1 character long.")
private String name;

public Customer() {}

public Customer(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("title", "Home");
    model.addAttribute("customers", customerDao.findAllByOrderByNameAsc());
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processFetch(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("title", "Home");
    model.addAttribute("customers", customerDao.findAllByOrderByNameAsc());
    model.addAttribute("c", customerDao.findById(customer.getId()));
    return "index";
}
```

and the View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="fragments::head"></head>
<body>
    <nav th:replace="fragments::nav"></nav>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title" th:text="${title}"></h1>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <form method="post" th:object="${customers}" style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;width:300px;margin-top:5%">
            <select class="form-control" name="customer">
                <option style="text-align:center" th:each="customer:${customers}" th:value="${customer.id}" th:text="${customer.name}"></option>
            </select>
            <input class="button" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;margin-top:30px" type="submit" value="Fetch" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 th:text="${c.get().name}"></h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Repository class:

```
public interface CustomerDao extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {
    public Iterable<Customer> findAllByOrderByNameAsc();
}
```

The error I try to submit the form is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

I'm not sure why it cannot find property 'name'. It should be part of the object.

I appreciate any insight into this!

Comment: Please be more specific about "does not work", and post your repository class. I suspect you're returning `Optional<Customer>`.

Comment: Can you print out the value of `customers` on the server side?  On the client side?  Also, confirm that replacing the fragments aren't actually causing the exception.

Comment: do you really get the error by submitting the form? Or do get the error by rendering the view?

Comment: I get the error when I submit the form. If I output the name and id to the console after I submit the form, it prints on the server side, but then when it hits the post controller and sends it to the view, that's when I get the error specifying that the property doesn't exist, which it does, cause it's already printed in the console. What I don't get is why c.get().name works, but c.name doesn't. even when I have specified setters and getters in my model class.